# Show that $(M_n)$ is an increasing sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X=[0,1]$, and suppose that $f_n:X \to X$ is an increasing sequence of functions for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $f(x)=\sup f_n(x)=\lim _{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ and $M_n=\sup_{x\in X} f_n(x)$. Prove that $(M_n)$ is an increasing sequence and that $\lim _ {n \to \infty} M_n=\sup_{x \in X} f(x)$.

I have no clue where to start with this problem, so any help is greatly appreciated.

I do know that $f(x)=\sup f_n(x)=\lim _{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ is simply the definition of pointwise convergence, and so $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)$. I also know that since $f_n(x)$ is an increasing sequence of functions, $f_n(x)<f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: To start, you know that $f_n(x) \geq f_m(x)$ for $n\geq m$, so if you take the $\sup$ over $X$ of both sides of the inequality, you get $M_n \geq M_m$ for $n \geq m$.  What can you say about the rest?

Comment: @Matt that gives us that $(M_n)$ is an increasing sequence. Then, I will need to use the fact that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ to somehow show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} M_n = \sup _{x \in X} f(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M=\sup_{x\in X}f(x)$ and $M_\infty =\lim_{n\to \infty} M_n$. Since $f(x) \geq f_n (x) $ for all $x \in X$ and all $n \in \mathbb N$ we have that $M \geq M_n$ so $M \geq M_\infty$.

Lets assume that $M_\infty < M$. Since $M_n$ is inscreasing we know that $f_n(x) \leq M_n \leq M_\infty$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and $x \in X$. Now taking the limit as $n \to \infty $ we have that $f(x) \leq M_\infty$ for all $x \in X$. But then $M_\infty$ is an upper bound for $f$ which is smaller than $M = \sup_{x\in X}f(x)$ (which is a contradiction).

Hence the only possibility is that $M=M_\infty$.